# Where to apply for more "URL Fetch calls" quota from google

Tags: google-apps-script

I use URL fetch calls in Adwords scripts to scrape various sources, most of all my own web pages. I find myself limited by the quota of 20 000 requests/24hours. https://script.google.com/dashboard . Where can I apply for a larger quota?

I have substantially large Adwords accounts.
My account managers and Adwords support didn't know the answer and finally sent me to the Adwords API support team. Adwords API support sent me here to stackoverflow. Thanks for any input.

Comment: I guess you need to sign up for a [gsuite](https://gsuite.google.com/pricing.html) to get higher quota

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/limits) which outlines various limits and limitations in AdWords scripts that you should be aware of. Also note that, Google Apps Script services impose daily quotas and hard limits on some features.

And as commented by @rckrd, to get a higher quota, you may want to sign up for G Suite. See this [page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) for more information on quota limits for Google Services.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. The problem is, that I cannot apply for G-Suite with a google account login email adress which im already using for other google products, like adwords, analytics, search console and so on. It just returns an error message of "google account already exists". Please advise.